# Given nonzero vectors $x$ and $y$, does there exist an invertible matrix $A$ such that $Ax=y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Given any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus\{0_n\}$, does there exist an invertible matrix $A$ such that $Ax=y$?

I was examining the orbits of set $\mathbb{R^n}$ under the action of the group $\mbox{GL}_n(R)$ by left multiplication, i.e., $$O_x = \left\{ A x \mid A \in \mbox{GL}_n(R) \right\}$$ and $x\in \mathbb{R^n}$. Since $O_0=\{0\}$, I thought there is only one more orbit of nonzero vectors. This can be shown if my above question holds true.

Comment: if $|x| = |y|,$ then a reflection matrix $R$ will do. otherwise, a reflection followed by a scaling should work.

Comment: @abel can you give a matrix? Do you mean a rotation or reflection?

Comment: To expand upon @abel's answer, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation

Comment: reflection matrix $R = 2uu^T/(u^Tu) - I$ where $u$ is either

Comment: @abel can you explain a bit??

Comment: this is continuation of my 2nd comment. pick $u = x+y$ form the reflection matrix. there is another method that i found on page 65 of the text canonical matrix by turnbull and aitken. there you construct a elementary row matrix but you need to know which component of $x$ is not zero.

Comment: I think rotations, reflections, etc, are a distraction. This is just basic linear algebra, as in copper.hat's answer below, and it works for any field, not just for ${\mathbb R}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a brute force approach to show existence.

Given a non-zero vector $v_1$ add vectors so that $v_1,...,v_n$ form a basis and let $V$ be the resulting matrix, that is
$V=\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & \cdots & v_n \end{bmatrix}$. Then $V e_1 = v$
($e_1$ is the vector $(1,0,\cdots,0)^T$). Note that $V$ is invertible.

So, given $x$, find $V_1$ such that $V_1 e_1 = x$, then $e_1 = V_1^{-1} x$.

Now, given $y$, find $V_2$ such that $V_2 e_1 = y$. then $V_2 V_1^{-1} x = y$, so letting $A = V_2 V_1^{-1}$ will do the trick.

**Aside**: If $\|v_1\| = 1$ above, the basis can be chosen to be orthonormal, and so the resulting $V$ will be orthogonal (unitary).

Hence we can find an orthogonal (unitary) $A$ such that ${ \|y\| \over \|x\| } Ax = y$.

Comment: what is $v$?? $V$ is the matrix with $v_1,v_2,..v_n$ in its columns??

Comment: $v$ is an arbitrary non-zero vector. I was just showing that you can find a $V$ such that $Ve_1 = v$.

Answer (score 2):

I will make copper.hat's answer more concrete by constructing the matrices for the case $n = 5.$

First I will deal with the case the first component of both $x$ and $y$ is $1.$
The matrix $$Y = \left( \begin{array}{lllll} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr y_2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr y_3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr y_4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr y_5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right)$$
and its inverse $$Y^{-1} =\left( \begin{array}{lllll} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr -y_2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr -y_3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr -y_4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr -y_5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right)$$ have the property $Ye_1 = y$ and $Y^{-1}y = e_1.$ In the same way form the matrices $X$ and its inverse $X^{-1}.$

Now, the matrix $YX^{-1}$ will send $x$ to $y$ for $YX^{-1}x = Ye_1 = y.$

If the first components of $y$ or $x$ are not $1$ use permutation matrices and scaling to make the first component of both to be $1.$